# Which Indra was adulterous?

Tags: indra

There was a comment posted [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/34717/how-many-indra-are-there-till-now#comment109198_34717), which says:

> Each day of Brahma has 14 Manvantars and each Manvantar has a different Indra. We are currently in the 7th Manvantar of the 51st day of Brahma and his each year has 360 days. **So there have been (50 x 360 x 14) + 7 Indras in total!** – [Amrit Dhara Apr 29 '19 at 6:50](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/16173/amrit-dhara)

There are a lot of discussions on Indra. Also there is a mention of he being adulterous. So this creates my question that which Indra was adulterous among these?

Comment: You can go through [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/42521/3869)

Comment: No i differ Indra is way below in taratamya tree in which 1, Sriman Narayana is the Moola purusha and not you tough :-). He comes in 8th step in the tree.. but he is above Rishi, Munis there 24 steps below him.. which is occupied by different Gods. Many purunas convey guhya artha were you to infer from the symbol or activity they perform or for which they designated gods. As Indra is Abhmanya devatha for Indriyas, like srothram, chakkshu, grahana, vak and thavak in addition to karmaya indiryas. Adultry is perform by indriya, @SrimannaryanaKV

Comment: since he is the God of that aspect he accrus no karma that is his job.. but these get activated based karma even he is not  resposible al the failures of human as he is devatha he does is activity by way of na aham kartha as service to god as there is no impact o karima